# Navbar links point to the same page when using anchors

Tags: joomla-3.x, weblinks, navigation

My site has two pages:

```
http://www.example.com/en
http://www.example.com/en/contacts
```

The pages both share a common navbar and some of the navbar links are to specific anchors *of the homepage.*

**These links do not work properly**, pointing to the same-named anchor in the *current* page instead.

I tried all of these syntaxes:

```
index.php?Itemid=1121&#anchor1
index.php?Itemid=1121&amp;#anchor1
http://www.example.com/en/#anchor1
```

- 1121 is the ItemID of the homepage;
- All anchors are HTML IDs;
- If no element of the current page has the anchor1 ID, the link does nothing;
- Both addresses work as intended if I use them inside an `<a href="`...`">link</a>` structure somewhere else on the page;
- Both addresses work as intended if I right click on the links and choose "open in another window/tab";
- The problem was already there before activating the SEF URL rewriting option;
- Changing `&` to `&amp;` does not solve the problem;
- Inspecting the element in Chrome gives me the following code:

  ```
  <a href="/en/#anchor1" data-uk-smooth-scroll="{offset: 0}">Home Page Anchor</a>
  ```

**What can I do to solve this problem?**

If relevant, I'm using Joomla 3.6.4, PHP 7.0.13 and the Luna theme from Yootheme (hence the uikit smoothscroll data). The behaviour is the same under IE 11.672.10586.0 and Chrome 54.0.2840.99 m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, just removing the smoothscroll js call fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this with this steps:

1. Create "hiden menu";
2. Create a blank article  in this hide menu with some like `<p> </p>`;
3. Set "home" in this blank article;
4. Now yours #anchors was working like a "one page site";

See this example:
http://www.sindha.org.br/lab/

I hope this helps;

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you are telling me to have my homepage is some page different than the ones I'm using. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, for me work with this steps. Im many try every time i have same page joomla reloads page and dont go to #anchors.